# What is the meaning of 商{あきな}いせず?

Tags: translation, meaning

What is the meaning of 商{あきな}いせず? It is common to use the stem verb plus せず instead of the negative form of the verb plus ず?

> 持ち込んだ荷物を商{あきな}いせず

Comment: @virmaior Which one are you talking about?  The phrase makes perfect sense.

Comment: @l'électeur I'm just completely wrong. It's not a first time for that.

Comment: @Veron ず is an old verbal auxiliary which means negative. It isn't frequently used but it is occasionally used in writings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[持]{も}ち[込]{こ}んだ[荷物]{にもつ}を[​商]{あきな}​いせず」

「商い」 means "business", "vending", etc.

「せず」＝「しない」 in meaning.

「商いせず」, therefore, means "not selling", "not trading", etc.

The whole phrase, thus, means ***"(Someone is) not selling the stuff that he has brought in."***