# Negative adjective 恐怖せず

Tags: nuances, verbs, negation

恐怖せず

I think it means “fearless”, but I don’t know the particle *sezu*. Is this old-fashioned?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. Also, [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-is-the-difference-between-the-negative-forms-%e3%81%9a-and-%e3%81%ac) seems relevant here.

Comment: There is also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29734/1628 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34135/1628. Please let us know if these answer your question. If not, please elaborate what exactly you want to know about せず.

Answer (score 1):

To my native ears it sounds a bit poetic. Not verbal.

Not necessarily old-fashioned.